# Q.For encoding error of ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspbian, libx264

I ran the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -threads 2 -codec:v libx264 -s:v 1280x720 -aspect:v 16:9 -b:v 256k -map 0 -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list stream.m3u8 streamfiles/stream%03d.ts
```

Execution result

```
ffmpeg version N-75926-gce0834b Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavcodec     57.  5.100 / 57.  5.100
  libavformat    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10159 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 10156 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 2400k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Illegal instruction
```

The result is that an error occurred.
Someone told me that it's an error if you do not put the option to `./configure` of `libx264`. That option is the `--extra-cflags='-march=armv6' --extra-ldflags='-march=armv6'`. Otherwise it would use the instruction of unsupported.

So I ran `./configure` with the option, then I ran the make and now I'm getting an error message:

```
common/arm/quant-a.S: Assembler messages:
common/arm/quant-a.S:362: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `rbit r1,r1'
common/arm/quant-a.S:363: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `rbit r1,r1'
Makefile:217: recipe for target 'common/arm/quant-a.o' failed
make: *** [common/arm/quant-a.o] Error 1
```

I do not know the meaning of this error. How should you deal me this error?

I use the machine is Raspberry PI B+ and my OS is Raspbian. I want to use `ffmpeg` and `libx264`.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried cross-compiling? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi

Comment: Do you need a cross-compiling to ffmpeg?
I do not know whether I should do download any crosstool-ng、、、

Comment: It's not  mandatory but it's quicker and might solve your issues.

Comment: I am following the same tutorial. The branch you suggested for x264 works for me. Alsa-lib version 1.1.0 works for me without errors on 28t Dec 2015. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error building libx264, but I got an older version to compile. It seems some recent changes to the library have broken building for armv6 processors (or there's a required compilation switch I don't know about).

My solution:

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264
cd x264
git checkout 3902ae02a0edede5d6c44cb3ee9e24e618c66e6a
```

then ./configure with required options, make, make install etc.

I'm trying to cross-compile ffmpeg on my desktop machine, following instructions [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi). I don't know if my solution works though, because I got stuck at the next step (alsa-lib seems to require python)!

Comment: Thanks -- I had the same problem, and I've just compiled that version of x264 successfully.  I'll see how far I get with alsa...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did a bisect on the history of x264, and the problem was introduced in commit 5c13589b, "Implement x284_decimate_score15/16/64_neon". Checking out its parent, 3902ae02, worked for me.